# Why does Stupefy not properly stun recipients during Dumbledore's Army training?

Tags: harry-potter

During Dumbledore's Army training, members practice stunning and frequently hit each other. However we never see anyone being revived with Rennervate.

Is this because they are too young and not powerful/well trained enough at this point for the effects to be as severe?

In summary, **why do Dumbledore's Army members not feel the full effects of being stunned?**